# replaceAll using predefined character classes in apache velocity

Tags: java, regex, velocity

Velocity seems to be having some trouble with string replacement:

```
#set( $stringOriginal = "some * oxdd --- strin+g here" )
#set( $stringAfter = $stringOriginal.replaceAll("\\W+","+") )
$stringAfter
```

and the non-word sections, remain untouched: it prints this

```
some * oxdd --- strin+g here
```

***But*** if I use `[^a-zA-Z_0-9]+` instead of the predefined class `\W`

```
#set( $stringOriginal = "some * oxdd --- strin+g here" )
#set( $stringAfter = $stringOriginal.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z_0-9]+","+") )
$stringAfter
```

everything's dandy

```
some+oxdd+strin+g+here
```

Attempting to escape with an odd number of `\` throws a
`Lexical error: org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.TokenMgrError:`
making it look like velocity tries to do some escaping of it's own.

I'm using the amazon-mturk cli, which comes with **velocity-1.5** and **velocity-tools-1.4**.

Comment: I didn't use `velocity` but is it possible that ``\`` isn't special character there in String literal? Could you try with `\W+` instead of `\\W+`? If that was the case then explanation would be that `\\W+` would represent text starting with ``\`` and having one or more `W` after it.

Comment: I tried with `\W`, `\\W`, `\\\W`, and `\\\\W` before posting. If it takes more than that, there's no sense in this world

Comment: that's funny. use a debugger to see what is passed to replaceAll ?

Comment: @luoluo, i want `some+oxdd+strin+g+here`; just the non word sections to be replaced with a `+`

Comment: @luoluo, i assume you mean inside a set directive; it throws errors.

Comment: yep, velocity escaping is all very funky - http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html -

Comment: maybe use single quoted string

Comment: A wild guess, can there be a typo in your original code. Maybe the `W` is not the `ascii W`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single `\` works on velocity-1.7

```
#set( $stringAfter = $stringOriginal.replaceAll("\W+","+") )
```

On velocity-1.5, indeed the escaping parsing seems out of wack. `"\\W"` in velocity means `"\\\\W"` in java (i.e. two backslashes), yet `"\W"` in velocity causes parsing error.

However, single quote works here on v1.5

```
#set( $stringAfter = $stringOriginal.replaceAll('\W+',"+") )
```

I wonder how do you express `\n` etc in velocity -- but my experimenting ends here.

While Velocity started as a "simple" template language, it adds more and more feature to mimic a "real" language and the syntax starts to get out of control :)

Comment: i'm getting `Lexical error: org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 2, column 51.  Encountered: "W" (87), after : "\"\\"`

Comment: @user3276552 - are you using the latest version?

Comment: I'm using the aws cli. It comes bundled with velocity-1.5 and velocity-tools-1.4 (the question's updated)

Comment: I downloaded v1.7, which was apparently released in **2010**. v1.5 was released in **2007**.

Comment: yeah, this isn't an ideal situation.  I haven't touched java before this; my company needs some stuff done that the amazon-turk web interface won't do. If there was an easier option, i'd take it.  Thanks for putting in the effort to help, sorry it's not simpler.

Comment: @user3276552 - well it's the library's fault. fortunately you already have a workaround.